# Single Frame Stalling in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've been building a game and a lengthy way through I noticed movement wasn't absolutely smooth and jittered randomly. I created a mockup program that reproduces this:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,400))

def create_lines():
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for i in range(0, 300):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,0,0), ((i * 15) , 0 ), ((i * 15), 1600),(1))

class moving_object(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/etc/7.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 200

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 2

def inputs():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

#create object, add to group 
sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
block = moving_object()
sprite_group.add(block)

while True:
    inputs()
    create_lines()
    sprite_group.draw(screen)
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.flip()
    sprite_group.update()
```

Here is a webm demonstrating the issue:
http://puu.sh/qC8cF/f05eff8a14.webm

There is a point where the movement isn't updated for that frame and the next frame after that it catches itself up, doing the missed frame and the additional present frame. This hiccuping is really concerning in a game that revolves around dodging.

I don't know how to fix it, tried changing the order the functions are called, especially tick, flip, draw and update. This isn't screen tearing either, it seems a frame just doesn't happen yet is made up for on the call after so the math is still being done properly...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood correctly, but what about if you tweak these 2 lines?

`self.rect.x += 1` instead `self.rect.x += 2`

`clock.tick(60)` instead `clock.tick(30)`

Also, you could try making your animation time-based, for example:

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


def create_lines():
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for i in range(0, 300):
        pygame.draw.line(
            screen, (255, 0, 0), ((i * 15), 0), ((i * 15), 1600), (1))


class moving_object(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/etc/7.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = 200


def inputs():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

# create object, add to group
sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
block = moving_object()
sprite_group.add(block)
t = 0

while True:
    timedelta = clock.tick(60)
    timedelta /= 500

    inputs()
    create_lines()

    block.rect.x = 50 * math.cos(t)
    block.rect.y = 100 + 50 * math.sin(t)

    sprite_group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    sprite_group.update()

    t += timedelta
```

Comment: I was able to seemingly fix the issue by not using pygames method of time and instead using time.sleep(0.333) as a substitute. It seems to be an issue with pygames method of obtaining time/their clock. In regards to using time.sleep for fps; I don't know if it's good practice or will lead to complications later on but it works...